# Glitch gradient effect

Tags: adobe-photoshop

what would you think is the best way to create a gradient effect like this:

[image: glitch effect]

Thanks

EDIT: Here is where I have started, I create a gradient within a thin stripe, and then duplicate and move the gradient slightly. but its very time consuming and It's not as smooth.

[image]

Comment: Possibly playing around with the scallop tool could create some of the belnding/warp effect this gradient has.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Make a gradient

[image]

- Convert to Smart Object > Filter > Stylize > Wind to your liking

[image]

- Liquify. I'd duplicate it first and Liquify the copy:

[image]

- Motion Blur. Again I'd duplicate it first and Blur the copy which will also allow you to lower the opacity after:

[image]